# C++ Create and Save OpenCV 16bit image pixelwise

Tags: c++, opencv

I would like to create a 16bit PNG-image with OpenCV by setting pixel values manually for noise generation. I tried the following:

```
cv::Mat img16(WINDOW_Y, WINDOW_X, CV_16UC3); // create 16 bit mat

float val, new_value;
float noise = 3.1343; // actually randomly generated by randomizer in (0..255)
for (int x = 0; x < WINDOW_X; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < WINDOW_Y; y++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            // get value from another CV_8UC3-mat
            val = img.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x)[i]; 
            // add up noise and scale to 16bit
            new_value = (val + noise)*255; 
            // avoid overflow at 2^16-1
            if (new_value > 65535) { 
                new_value = 65535;
            }
            // set the value to 16bit mat
            img16.at<cv::Vec3s>(y,x)[i] = (short) new_value;
        }
    }
}
// write to PNG file, since PNG supports 16 bit
cv::imwrite(file + ".png", img16);
```

What I get as output seems to be 16 bit:

```
 $ identify output.png 
 output.png PNG 128x128 128x128+0+0 16-bit PseudoClass 65536c
```

But it shows up monotone grey (#808080) while I expect a heterogeneous image. What's wrong with it?

Comment: You're writing the file *inside* that loop??

Comment: img16.at<short>(y,x) = (short) set; // also please avoid the name 'set', since there's a std:: container with the same name already

Comment: Mat(WINDOW_Y, WINDOW_X, CV_16U); will give you a single channel Mat, it looks like you are setting pixels as though it has 3 channels. If you want 3 channels, use CV_16UC3.

Comment: Oh, no I'm actually not writing inside the loop, I made mistake whilst formatting this question. Thanks for the hint, also changed the "set" name, didn't know this. I will test whether 3C will change something on this issue.

Comment: Using CV_16U**C3** was good, it solves the *free or corruption (out): 0x09556fc8* message, but monotone grey is still the same, without vertical black though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whenever you see yourself writing per-pixel loops in opencv, - hold on, and try to find something builtin instead.

```
Mat ocv=Mat(200,200,CV_16UC3); // as you can only save 16bit *unsigned* as png or tif
theRNG().fill(ocv,RNG::UNIFORM,0,65535);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That works great. But still wondering what was wrong with my admittedly inconvenient code.

Comment: you weren't strict enough about the image type. once you create the Mat with CV_16UC3, you would have to *stick* to img.at<Vec3s>(y,x) consitantly